# Bootstrap collapse is not working with the each loop of Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I'm retrieving a list of locations in the following template

```
<template name="explore">
    <h2>Explore Places</h2>
    <ul>
        {{#each locations}}
        <h4><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#info">{{name}}</a></h4>
        <p id="info" class="collapse">{{{information}}}</p>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
 </template>
```

Whenever a location is clicked I want to show its corresponding hidden information by the use of the bootstrap collapse. But clicking on any link in the list always shows information of the first item in the list.

Comment: at the first look, don't you need a `<li>` as well?

Comment: Added it. Doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, I was using the same 'id' for each collapsible tag:

```
<template name="explore">
    <h2>Explore Places</h2>
    <ul>
        {{#each locations}}
        <h4><button class="btn btn-mini" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{name}}">{{name}}</button></h4>
        <li>
            <p id="{{name}}" class="collapse">{{{information}}}</p>
        </li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>
```